# How to restart Applications launcher (Slingshot) if it crashes

Tags: release-freya, slingshot

Sometimes (rarely) it happens that Slingshot launcher is neither accessible by shortkey or by clicking Applications on panel.

How to force it to restart without logging off?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The parts of the desktop like Gala (the window manager), Wingpanel, Plank (the dock), and Slingshot (the apps menu) are automatically restarted by a process called [Cerbere](https://launchpad.net/cerbere).

You'll only need to end the process for Slingshot and Cerbere will automatically restart it. You can do this in Terminal (shortcut: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>) with:

```
killall slingshot-launcher
```

Comment: how is it in Loki? `killall slingshot-launcher
slingshot-launcher: no process found` - also [How to access help for Slingshot launcher?](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/10697/170).

Answer (score 10):

`killall slingshot-launcher` worked for me

Answer (score 0):

The process that [Cerbere](https://launchpad.net/cerbere) keeps running in background is `slingshot-launcher --silent` so I guess that command might do the trick.

Comment: I will have to wait for that to happen again. I have tried with `slingshot-launcher`, but that doesn't work and then logged out :)

Comment: Well, the obvious progress then is to edit your question and post the output of that command so we could see exactly what went wrong.