# How to access help for Slingshot launcher?

Tags: release-loki, slingshot

Slingshot is installed and works fine.

[image]

But trying to get some info on it in terminal:

```
cipeos@cipeos-HP:~$ slingshot-launcher -h
slingshot-launcher: command not found
cipeos@cipeos-HP:~$ slingshot-launcher --help
slingshot-launcher: command not found
cipeos@cipeos-HP:~$ slingshot-launcher -help
slingshot-launcher: command not found
cipeos@cipeos-HP:~$
```

Also:

```
killall slingshot-launcher
slingshot-launcher: no process found
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can search for other questions, in terms of customising the menus, I'm not sure what you need to achieve, but this is what I've found so far...

To find out about commands you can type:

```
man slingshot-launcher
```

To locate installed files you can do:

```
dpkg -L slingshot-launcher
```

You need to run commands to actually use it via wingpanel, which you can interact with on the command line. I believe the command to show it is:

```
wingpanel --toggle-indicator app-launcher
```

man page for slingshot is mostly:

OPTIONS
       -h, --help
              Show help message and exit

```
   -v, --version
          Print version info and exit

   -s, --silent
          Launch Slingshot as a background process without it appearing visually

   -c, --command-mode
          Not implemented yet

   --display=DISPLAY
          X display to use
```

Comment: I'm interested in the possibility of the command `wingpanel --toggle-indicator app-launcher` taking other arguments that would effectively launch an application. - Is it possible? - That would solve my other problem here: [Startup command to execute a desktop file and show its icon in dock](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/10696/170) I think.

Comment: You should be able to execute a .desktop file from terminal too: `chmod +x ~/.local/share/applications/<your file>.desktop` have you tried this? Does it produce the icon in the dock?

Comment: Please comment under the other question if the case. I have added the details in the linked question; `If I simply execute the desktop file in the file manager, the terminal icon is shown.`